# PHP: Body is displaying 0

Tags: php, return, echo, anonymous-function

```
$Test = function($text) {
        $html  = '<!DOCTYPE HTML>';
        $html .= '<html>';
        $html .= '<head>';
        $html .= '<noscript>';
        $html .= '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/?javascript=false" />';
        $html .= '</noscript>';
        $html .= '</head>';
        $html .= '<body>';
        $html .= '<div>' + $text + '</div>';
        $html .= '</body>';
        $html .= '</html>';
        return $html;
    };

    $html = $Test('Test');

    echo($html);
    exit();
```

This is my code, I was testing Anonymous functions (http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), why is it that the noscript /noscript displays just fine in the Inspector but the div /div gets replaced by 0?

Comment: Welcome from your journey from JS to PHP. In the land of PHP it's not every thing identical to the land of JS

Comment: *facepalm* periods instead of pluses... 8 years of PHP experience and I make such a rookie mistake...

Comment: Should make an 'answer' so I can upvote you for helping me realize my mistake :)